# Get GitLab "my projects" tab as JSON or XML?

Tags: json, xml, gitlab

Is it possible to get serialized output of some sort from the `/dashboard/projects` screen in GitLab?

(I want to track differences and alert myself when someone assigns me a new project. One option is of course to build a script that iterates through the HTML pages, but if there's a way to get all projects at once -- preferably in a machine-friendly format -- that's even better.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that usually this kind of alert are not strictly needed, because usually the *assignment* workflow is about issue/MR assignment (which usually end up in a email in you inbox), anyway..

You should take a look at GitLab API or, even better, use an already existing project like [Python GitLab](https://github.com/python-gitlab/python-gitlab)
It is a Python client implementation of GitLab API and also have an handy `gitlab` command line tool that can give you the required data in a human/machine readable format

Comment: Agreed that this is not strictly needed -- something like JIRA, Trac or Redmine is usually better for actual assignment, and I encourage organizations to use those tools rather than truly relying on this type of work-around. That said, thanks for nudging me toward that Python client. It could be quite useful for certain situations.

Comment: You don't need neither Jira nor trac or whatever. Just use GitLab issue/MR assignment

Comment: Nice -- I hadn't even known about that tool. Very interesting.